# Run prestashop in docker

Tags: php, docker, prestashop

I'd like to run prestashop in docker container. I don't want to pull an already created image, I want to create my own from files provided in .zip folder downloaded from official prestashop site.

Answer (score 1):

You could use their [official Dockerfile](https://github.com/PrestaShop/docker/blob/master/images/1.7.6.1/Dockerfile) as a starting point:

```
FROM prestashop/base:5.6-apache
LABEL maintainer="Thomas Nabord <thomas.nabord@prestashop.com>"

ENV PS_VERSION 1.7.6.1

# Get PrestaShop
ADD https://www.prestashop.com/download/old/prestashop_1.7.6.1.zip /tmp/prestashop.zip

# Extract
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/data-ps \
    && unzip -q /tmp/prestashop.zip -d /tmp/data-ps/ \
    && bash /tmp/ps-extractor.sh /tmp/data-ps \
    && rm /tmp/prestashop.zip
```